# How to differentiate between a mobile POS device and an android phone

Tags: java, android, mobile, reader, pos

I am building an app that runs on an android POS device and can also run on a real android device.. now I want to be able to determine if the app is installed on a real android device or the mobile POS device and I don't want to check the build version or model.. I will like to use something more definite and unique.. Please I need help

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the mobile POS device.

Answer (score 0):

Every Android POS has an specialized Android OS which is customized by the manufacture. This specialized OS, limit you in system setting and some other important configuration. So your application cannot be installed on the mobile POSes in the field and probably you need add an external package (something like sign-plugin) to install your app on them. This (or these) external package(s) is(are) provided by the Manufacture of the POS. If you can install a regular app on your POS, it is probably you have a DEVELOP terminal.